# Move QGLWidget with only slots to different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opengl

I have a QT program which receives QBytearray's from the Kinect and then processes them to visible images on the screen in a QGLWidget. This QGLWidget runs in the GUI Thread, just like the rest of the GUI. The class that fires the Kinect images runs in a different thread. All comminutation is done trough signals and slots.

Sometimes the GUI thread locks and then the OpenGLWidget also locks and I want to fix that. To do this, I need a QT Slot to run in a different thread then the rest of the GUI. I know this is possible, but all examples I saw use a run method, which gets started in a different thread and then runs on its own.

But I use a slot to receive the images, which means that it does not run constantly but only if there is an image available for rendering. Can I create a thread and put this slot in the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a recent project I "solved" this by [shaving some yaks](http://catb.org/jargon/html/Y/yak-shaving.html), err, write some routing wrappers.

```
class FooClass : public QThread
{
Q_OBJECT

  /* ... */

public slots:
/* to thread loopback signals */
void setBufferCount(
    unsigned int buffercount ) {
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "_priv_loslot_setBufferCount",
            Qt::QueuedConnection,
            Q_ARG(unsigned int, buffercount) ); 
    }

private slots:
/*
 * private loopback slots
 * ^^^^    ^^       ^^^^
 *
 * These slots are connected to the coresponding frontend
 * signals. Calling a frontend signal will send a invocation
 * between the threads, calling the loopback slots within
 * the worker thread.
 */
void _priv_loslot_setBufferCount(unsigned int buffercount);

  /* ... */
}
```

By calling or connecting to the public slots the internal wrapping by calling *invokeMethod* on a *Qt::QueuedConnection* did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper class and move your logic there. So your Widget class will be in main thread, and it should emit signals which will be processed in helper class in a different thread.